# Is a catalog mandatory to even use Azure Dev Box?

Tags: azure, azure-dev-box

I have set up Azure Dev Box as per the Azure how-to article "Quickstart: Configure the Microsoft Dev Box Preview service" [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-box/quickstart-configure-dev-box-service?tabs=AzureADJoin), including creating a dev centre, networking/vnet, dev box pool, project, dev box definition etc. but I get the following error message when I view the project -

> The dev center that contains this project does not have a catalog
> assigned. Environments cannot be deployed in this project until a
> catalog containing at least one template has been assigned.

Additionally, when I go to dev box and try to create a dev box using the dev box portal I get the following error message even though I have set up a pool:

> Cannot create dev boxes Your administrator has not created any dev
> box pools to enable dev box creation. Please contact your
> administrator to request an update, or try again later.

Interestingly, the catalog feature is not even mentioned in the QuickStart above so must be quite new?

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Catalog is not part of Dev Box, but is used in Azure Deployment Environments under the banner Devcenter.

Both Microsoft Dev Box and Azure Deployment Environments use several common Devcenter components to drive their experiences. Central to these is the concept of Projects. A project is what binds the developer access to developer workstations through Dev Box and the relevant templates from ADE.

I've contributed to a repo that helps you familiar with the concepts and IaC to help get you up and running quicker : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Devcenter

Answer (score 0):

The user should have these permissions "DevCenter Dev Box User" and "DevCenter Project Admin" on Dev center to be able to create a dev box on the portal.